# Migrated from TFS to GIT to SVN. In SVN all the version dates are resetting to current date instead of historic dates

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tfs

We are retiring TFS Box and moving our Repo from TFS to SVN. We could sucessfully migrate from TFS = GIT = SVN , however the code history information contains current dates instead of historic dates in SVN.

Please find the below steps which we used to migrate.

STEP1: Install Chocolatey installer
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin

STEP 2: Install Git-TFS tool
cinst gittfs

STEP 3: Clone the TFS Repository into GIT Repositiry with history
git-tfs clone http://:8080  $/QECG/Development/Source/TestSVN D:\WORKAREA\SVN

STEP 4: Initialize the SVN Server Repository
git svn init -s --prefix=svn/ "http:///svn/tst01"

STEP 5: Fetch the data from the svn repository
git svn fetch --all

STEP 6: Create a backup
git rev-parse svn/trunk

STEP 7:
echo ID(STEP5) ID(STEP6) >> .git/info/grafts

STEP 8:
git filter-branch -- ^svn/trunk --all

STEP 9: 
git svn rebase

STEP 10:
git svn dcommit

STEP 11: Set the remote origin path where local repository is copied
git remote add origin D:\WorkArea\SVN\Cognos.git

STEP 12: Fetch the data from the local repository
git fetch origin

STEP 13: check out the files into origin/master and move the backup into old_master
git checkout -b old_master origin/master

STEP 14:Apply all history downloaded from TFS
git rebase --onto master --root

STEP 15: Commit the files into SVN Repository
git svn dcommit

Cheers

Sandeep

Comment: Did you check timestamps in Git-repo?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/files/tfs2svn/

Answer (score 1):

Server based source control systems generally don't allow you to set historical dates. You are migration data now, so the date is now.